# Is there any inequality involving the Frobenius norm and the dimension of matrix?

Tags: matrix-norms, linear-matrix-inequality

Let $A$ be a $m \times r$ matrix and $B$ be a $r \times n$ matrix, I wonder if there exists an inequality like the following:
$$
\left \| AB \right \|_F \leq f(m,r,n)g(A,B) ,
$$
or
$$
\left \| AB \right \|_F \ge f(m,r,n)g(A,B) ,
$$
where $f(m,r,n)$ is a function of the dimension of matrix $m,r,n$, and $g(A,B)$ is a function of $A$ or $B$.
For example, does $\left \| AB \right \|_F \leq mr^2n \left \| A \right \|_F$ (here $f(m,r,m) = mr^2n$ is a function of $m$, $r$ and $n$, and $g(A,B) = \left \| A \right \|_F$ is a function of $A$) ?

I looked through the matrix reference books, but could not find any satisfactory answer, only some less relevant ones like this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1706997/what-is-the-lower-bound-on-the-frobenius-norm-of-a-product-of-square-matrices). Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The Frobenius norm is sub-multiplicative since it is an operator norm. Meaning:
$$\|AB\|_F \leq \|A\|_F\|B\|_F.$$
Is this what you are looking for? I think [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) contains good explanations for this.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your effort, but this is not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. In that case I think you should be more specific with your question, as there are many inequalities that satisfy the criteria in your question. E.g. I took $f(m, r, n) = 1$ and $g(A,B) = \|A\|_F\|B\|_F$. Maybe you want to put some conditions on $g$?

Comment: Thank you for your friendly advice. I will modify the description of this question.